# Some items are not translated in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I added a local to my project in the sites app and can display translated content properly when using the /locale/path.
The problem I have is with a custom content app which displays in English (the default locale) and the navigation menu bar also appears in English although there is a translated navigation title for every page.

What could be the reason?

The code to retrieve the custom content app is:

```
<div class="row-fluid foo-content">
  [#assign articles = cmsfn.contentByPath("/", "articles") ]
  [#assign article = cmsfn.children(articles, "lib:article")?sort_by("publish_date")?first ]
  <div class="span4 newsroom">
    <h4>${i18n.get('footer.newsroom')}</h4>
    <section class="foo-container clearfix">
      <div class="news-date"> 
        <span class="date">${article.publish_date?string.dd}</span> 
        <span class="month">${article.publish_date?string.MMMM}</span> 
        <span class="year">${article.publish_date?string.yyyy}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p class="upper">${article.title}</p>
        <div class="fsize-12">
          ${article.description?substring(0, 170)}...
        </div>
        <p>            
          <a class="link-readmore" href="${cmsfn.link(cmsfn.siteRoot(content))}client/articles/view-article~${article.@name}~.html">${i18n.get('footer.readMore')}</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    [#assign rootNode = cmsfn.contentByPath("/alqasemi/articles")]
    [#if rootNode??]
      <a class="btn-blue" href="${cmsfn.link(rootNode)}">${i18n.get('footer.viewAlqaswmiNews')}</a>
    [/#if]
  </div>
```

Comment: Could be many things. But typically, template retrieving the data from your custom content app is ignoring (not passing on) the locale set for the page thus always retrieving content in default language (english).
Try to add code retrieving content from content app for display on the page to your question to make it possible to find out more.

Comment: @Jan I added the code to retrieve the content app. it is called articles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that you are creating links manually to your articles here:

```
  <a class="link-readmore" href="${cmsfn.link(cmsfn.siteRoot(content))}client/articles/view-article~${article.@name}~.html">${i18n.get('footer.readMore')}</a>
```

Same way as you translate text of the link, you also need to provide locale to the `view-article` page/template so it knows what to translate to. You can look for details in the `link.ftl` of the demo project. Copied from there (should therefore work in 6.2.x), try to change the link to something like:

```
  [#assign target = cmsfn.contentByPath("/client/articles/view-article")!]
  [#assign link = cmsfn.link(target)!]
  [#assign articleName = article.@name!]

  <a href="${getDynamicLink(link, articleName)}">${i18n.get('footer.readMore')}</a>
```

where `getDynamicLink()` function would look like:

```
[#function getDynamicLink link itemName omitExtension=false]
    [#local dynamicLink = ""]
    [#if link?ends_with(".html")]
        [#local dynamicLink = link?replace(".html", "~"+itemName+"~")]
    [#else]
        [#local dynamicLink = link+"~"itemName+"~"]
    [/#if]        [#if !omitExtension]
        [#local dynamicLink += ".html"]
    [/#if]        [#return dynamicLink]
[/#function]
```

(Disclaimer: didn't check if the above code actually runs, there might be typos, but should give you the direction of the solution)

Comment: Thanks. Where is the locale referenced in your solution?

Comment: `cmsfn.link(target)` will take a note of the current locale and ensure it is included in the generated output, which you then only enrich with the selector (part between `~`)

Comment: The solution does not address the problem. The issue is that ${article.title} and ${article.description?substring(0, 170)} are displayed in english even though the arabic locale is requested in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the content not being localized is that the content from the custom content app is not wrapped for translation be default.

The solution is to add cmsfn.wrapForI18n(content) to the content and then the output will match the applied locale.

So this line:

```
 [#assign article = cmsfn.children(articles, "lib:article")?first]
```

Should be:

```
 [#assign article = cmsfn.wrapForI18n(cmsfn.children(articles, "lib:article")?first)]
```